# Regex replacement doesn't work with strings that include $1, $2, etc

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I need to replace the content between some xml tags to give it new values. I ran into a problem, and it is that some passwords contain signs like $1, that causes the replace with regex not to work as expected, as if the second parameter read it as a regex instead of a simple string.

This is an example:

```
const example = "<password>PASSWORD123</password>";
// we look for what is between the password tags for AU84$19*
const replaced = example.replace(/(?<=<password>)(.*?)(?=\s*<\/password>)/, "AU84$19*");
console.log(replaced); // output: AU84PASSWORD1239*
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried `AU84\$19*"`?

Comment: The `$` in the replacement must be doubled, `AU84$$19*`

Comment: the problem is that the passwords are very varied, this is just an example, so I would have to consider each of the cases that can be interposed by a regex